# How to call a JSP tag within a POJO

Tags: jsp, tags, include, custom-tag, requestdispatcher

I have a Java Bean used in a

```
<jsp:useBean id="controller" class="the.Pojo" scope="page"/>
```

I put in this Pojo things that I need: like the `request`, the `response` .. so I can include another jsp with `RequestDispatcher`.

What I need to do is to include a `custom tag`, I can put this custom tag in a JSP and incldue that JSP, but I was wondering if there's another way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can include a `custom tag` inside a Java (POJO) class. You better go ahead with including it in a `JSP`.

Still, I would like to hear what others have to say and find some interesting solutions.

This approach of using a POJO which includes other JSPs itself is quite interesting :-)